# Creating a vector of a class type inside another class

Tags: c++, class

I have run into an issue concerning classes. My goal is to model some population with a certain number of individuals possessing different characteristics. Concerning the scope, I have something like this:

-individual.h --> contains a class called individual:

```
class Individual
{
     public:
          //some characteristics, I will use random values here
          double a = 14.0;
          double b = 6.0;
}
```

-population.h --> contains a class called population:

```
class Population
{
     public:
           std::vector<Individual> populationVector;
}
```

What I thus want to do is create a population vector that contains a certain number of my class individuals, using something like this.

```
vector<Individual> populationVector( 100, Individual() );
```

When I call `populationVector` in my `main.cpp` the compiler does not give an error. When I consecutively try to use a simple loop to read out the vector contents to the screen, it gives an

> operand type error

(and yes, I included the relevant libraries in each file).

EDIT: loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < populationVector.size(); i++)
      std::cout << populationVector[i] << "\n";
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. You didn't provide the code for how you "_try to use a simple loop to read out the vector contents to the screen_".

Comment: Why don't you show us that "simple loop"?

Comment: @eneski I added the loop, my apologies. The arrows after std::cout give the operand error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`populationVector[i]` returns an object of type `Individual`. You didn't define an overload for `operator<<`. That's the reason why you get an error at

```
std::cout << populationVector[i] << "\n";
```

The compiler doesn't know how to print objects of your class to console. You have to implement a function like

```
std::ostream &ostream(std::ostream &os, const Individual& inv) {
    return os << inv.a << " " << inv.b << "\n";    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it. I learned something new in the process :)

Comment: Next time provide a [mcve] and people will help you much faster. It's difficult to understand your problem with only some lines of code.

Comment: You're right. My goal was to keep it as simple as possible, but I'll be more elaborate next time. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can not 'call your population vector'. You have to create an object of `Population` and then access its member.

```
#include "Population.h"
int main()
{
  Population pop;
  pop.populationVector.insert(pop.populationVector.begin(), 100, Individual() );
}
```

But normally you do not want to expose your internal members to the calling code. 
So `populationVector` should be private or protected and `Population` should offer functions to ineract with the individuals.

Comment: The loop is inside a member of `Population`. The error message is `operand type error`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I should have worded my question better, the code I supplied you was very barebones, the real problem was outputting the values that were stored in the vector.

Comment: @ThomasSablik according to his wording, he accesses the vector from the main.cpp.

Comment: @Matton968 yes the question is of very bad quality

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes your right - i overlooked this. in version 1 it was not shown that prominently.